# unexpected - TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: python-2.6

I know what this error means, but I see it in a very unexpected place:

```
if rate and len(rate) == 1:
```

*TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()*

Context is:

```
rate = re_search_once("(\d+)", ratetxt)
if rate and len(rate) == 1:
```

where re_search_once is just a syntactic sugar for regexp extraction.

Anyway, whatever "rate" is, how comes that Python tries to evaluate the second part of "and" for NoneType? (in this case it's just None, a sole value of NoneType)

I can't check the real value of "rate", just noticed it in the logs.

using python 2.6.5 on Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS

Updated, contents of

```
def re_search_once(pattern, string, flags=0):
    if string is None:
        return None
    mo = re.compile(pattern).search(string, flags)
    if mo:
        gs = mo.groups()
        if len(gs) == 1:
            return gs[0]
        else:
            return gs
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: what is the value of ratetxt?

Comment: you could also post the contents of re_search_once, maybe there is an error there.

Comment: are you sure this is the line that causes the error? running that line of code with rate set to None doesn't result in an error

Comment: added re_search_once to the question;
"ratetxt" is a string or None, and I have a check before the lines in question:
`if ratetxt:`

Comment: _codebox_, same here, and it shouldn't give any errors due to lazy evaluation... But this error in the log clearly shows the problem exists

Comment: check whether  mo.groups()  is none